# Transforming pandas series into 2D numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use OneHot encoder in the following series:

```
1       redução
2       redução
3       redução
4       redução
         ...   
1969     normal
1970     normal
1971     normal
1972     normal
1973     normal
Length: 1974, dtype: object
```

But it's returning me the following error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['redução' 'redução' 'redução' ... 'normal' 'normal' 'normal'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I already tried the approach above and also tried `np.array(s.values.tolist())` and it also didn't work, can anyone help me with this please?

This series has actually 3 unique values, that's why I'm trying to use OneHotEncoder

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to one hot encode my pandas data frames:

```
df_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df['col'])

df = pd.concat([df, df_dummy], axis=1)
```